# What is the significance of these colors in Witcher season 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-witcher

In The Witcher season 2 the main antagonist Voleth Meir appears in dreams to only three people, Yennefer, Fringilla, and Francesca. The first appearance in dreams is in the form of hooded and robed figures. The colour of the robes is White, Black and Red for the three of them. Is there any significance of these colors? Also does this have any connection to any folklore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's parallels between Voleth Meir and Baba Yaga, who is a figure in Russian folklore. Among other things, Baba Yaga lives in a hut deep in the forest; a hut that can move around on chicken legs.

There's also mention of Baba Yaga having three Riders who serve her, and that's even detailed in some RL stories. For example, this is on the [Russian National Tourist Office page for the UK](https://www.visitrussia.org.uk/blog/baba%20yaga%20%E2%80%93%20russia%E2%80%99s%20wicked%20witch%20of%20the%20east%20(but%20not%20all%20the%20time!)/)

> Baba Yaga rules over the elements. Her faithful servants are the White Horseman, the Red Horseman and the Black Horseman. Fortunately, she appears to have no power over the pure of heart.

Most notable here of course is the colours of the Riders - namely Black, Red, and White respectively, the same colours of the hooded figures Voleth Meir presents herself as. By all indications, this was done to strengthen that parallel.

Comment: This is also mentioned in "The Witcher's Bestiary: Season 2" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EozUgn4qXVU&t=508s